# How to connect to mysql from excel 2011

Tags: mysql, excel, odbc

I am using excel 2011 o  mac os mavericks.  I am trying to connector to mysql do use pivot tables.  I tried to instal. mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.6-osx10.7-x86-64bit-2.dmg but I get an error with no explanation.

So..how do I deal with odbc,excel, and mysql?  Is is possible to access mysql from mac os to mysql?  It seems that its not so easy sad to say.

Any clear blog wth update info?  A dummies guide I cant find?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might try OpenLink Software's ODBC driver for this situation.  http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/?s=excel